# C program running in background as daemon, only spawning Gtk windows when needed

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk

I wrote a daemon in C that polls a server for a boolean value. If true, it does nothing, if false, I want it to spawn a Gtk window the user can interact with.

My main(...) function spawns a thread that polls the server, which I already implemented using pthread. I want the main(...) function to also spawn a second thread, which opens a Gtk window. my problem is that I can only open one window at a time the way I implemented it in a simple test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define PROG_NAME "org.lwtw.laut-server"

static void ack (GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
    printf("Acknowledged!\n");
}

static void alarm_dialog (GtkApplication *app)
{
    GtkWidget *win;
    GtkWidget *ack_btn;
    GtkWidget *box;
    GtkWidget *btn_box;
    GtkWidget *label;
    GtkWidget *icon;

    win = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(win), "Laut Server");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(win), 300, 200);

    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(win), box);

    icon = gtk_image_new_from_icon_name("insync-error", GTK_ICON_SIZE_DIALOG);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), icon, true, true, 5);

    label = gtk_label_new("An alarm signal was received");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), label, true, true, 5);

    btn_box = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), btn_box, true, true, 5);

    ack_btn = gtk_button_new_with_label("Acknowledge Signal");
    g_signal_connect(ack_btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(ack), NULL);
    g_signal_connect_swapped(ack_btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), win);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(btn_box), ack_btn);

    gtk_widget_show_all(win);
}

static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
    alarm_dialog(app);
}

void gui_main (void *data)
{
    GtkApplication *app;

    app = gtk_application_new(PROG_NAME, G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), 0, NULL);
    g_object_unref(app);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (getc(stdin) != 'q') {
        pthread_t d_thread;
        pthread_create(&d_thread, NULL, (void *) gui_main, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: How can I have two threads running concurrently, with one polling the server and the other handling the opening and closing of any amount of Gtk windows at the same time, all asynchronously?

Comment: I'm not sure GTK can run multiple GUIs or not. Try a multi-process design?

Comment: Why do you think you need threads? Just call `g_application_hold()`, and on activate make and close as many windows as you want.

Comment: I need multithreading because I have the polling thread, which should not be interrupted at any point. Also, I plan to implement another thread that handles connections over a socket, so I can write a client that communicates with my daemon.

Comment: Use Gio for networking which handles async threading for you.

Comment: Your windows creating function (`alarm_dialog`) is bound to the *activate* signal that, AFAIK, is triggered once. If you bound it to a multiple event you'll get multiple GtkWindows. And, as a side note, you are leaking that windows.